# Why do I need to add dependencies' babel plugin to my project?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

The original quesiont was put on github issue: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/5803, but seems no response, so I think stackoverflow would be better place to ask:

The problem is:

When I add third party react component to my project, I always find out this:

```
Module build failed: ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "transform-object-assign" specified in "/Users/apple/Documents/.../react-z/node_modules/react-slick/.babelrc" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to
```

The third party component that I imported needs a babel plugin that I don't need.

I can add to my project, of course, then I add another third party react component, which needs babel-plugin-transform-replace-object-assign.

This quite embarrasses me that they do similar things, but I need to add them both to my project to make them work.

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-object-assign",
    [
      "transform-replace-object-assign",
      "object.assign"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Can someone explain why or show me how to do it in right way?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You need to exclude `node_modules/` from `babel-loader` so it doesn't try to transpile your dependencies:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It works, but I still need to add those to package to my project dependencies, right? Otherwise, it still tells me Unknown plugin.

Comment: No, your dependencies (are/should be) publishing transpiled versions to npm - e.g. here's what react-slick publishes: https://unpkg.com/react-slick/lib/ Arguably they shouldn't be publishing development-only files like `.babelrc` to npm, but in this case you would have been double-transpiling and never known it :)

Comment: I found out they fix the issue in their latest release. Cheers. Thanks a lot, @Jonny.